# How do I find the lowest point of a binary image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, canny-operator

After applying deep learning object detection and several image processing filters, at the end I have got the following image. 
**Here is the image**

[image]

**I want to find the redpoint coordinate frame.**

[image]

In order to get closer to the answer and remove those unwanted lines. I used a mask and here is the final result.

**My question is how can I find one point in the lowest point of this image?**

[image]

Comment: The red point does not appear to belong to the "circle".

Comment: To @YvesDaoust, it belongs to the circle, the tire is flat, that is why you see that

Comment: What is the square around it ?

Comment: it is from object detection algorithm.

Comment: where is your attempt/code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution is to use [`cv2.HoughCircles`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) to detect round shapes in your image.

I used an example from [pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/21/detecting-circles-images-using-opencv-hough-circles/) as base for my code, and added the low part of the circle with the output from the detected circle in `HoughCircles`. The result is in the image below:

[image: lowpointcircle]

Since this function returns the `[x, y, r]` (center point and radius of the circle) you can easily find the lowest part of the circle doing:

```
low_point = [x, y + r]
```

Remember that you can **play around** with the parameters from the `cv2.HoughCircles()` function.

You can see the Jupyter Notebook I used in [this Github page.](https://github.com/leomariga/StackOverflowSolutions/blob/master/bottompoint.ipynb).

The code I used:

```py
# import the necessary packages
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    # load the image, clone it for output, and then convert it to grayscale
    image = cv2.imread('img_circle.png')
    output = image.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #cv2.imshow("test", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.title('my picture')
    plt.show()

    # detect circles in the image
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 100,
                               param1=100, param2=40,
                               minRadius = 130, maxRadius = 0)

    # ensure at least some circles were found
    if circles is not None:
        # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

        # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            # draw the circle in the output image
            cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)

            # Draw low point of the circle 
            cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 10, y - 10 + r), (x + 10, y + 10 + r), (0, 0, 255), -1)

        # show the output image
        plt.imshow(np.hstack([image, output]))
        plt.title('my picture')
        plt.show()

        cv2.imwrite( "lowPoint.jpg", np.hstack([image, output]));
```

Comment: Hey, @Leonardo Mariga please check the issue part of the GitHub, I asked a question :)

Comment: Hum... I couldn't find any opened issues on GitHub... Where did you asked the question? Can you send me the link? I would happily answer it =)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find the row number of the lowest row in the image that is non-black. So you can do this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
img = cv2.imread('tyre.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)                                           

# Get X, Y coordinates of non-black pixels
y, x = np.nonzero(img)
```

If you now look at `y` you can see row 246 is the last row with any non-black pixel.

```
# Look at y, specifically y[-1]                                                                                     
array([ 80,  80,  80, ..., 246, 246, 246])
```